# Neutral points inside square where Charges are on vertices of sqare

Tags: electrostatics

Four equal point charges are kept ﬁxed at the four vertices of square. How many neutral points( i.e. points where the electric ﬁeld vanishes) will be found inside the square? 
Some people say there are 5 neutral points . 1 at the centre and 4 others on the middle of the side of the square. But i can not understand how the other four points are neutral .

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 neutral points. Only one (the center) is a null point, the others are simply points of equilibrium where if a charged particle was placed there it wouldn't move. These occur at the sides, or near the sides, as you can resolve the forces on them to zero. It's similar to the difference between local minimum and local maximum both being points of inflection.

Some fairly good diagrams of the process [here](https://www.quora.com/4-equal-point-charges-are-kept-fixed-at-4-vertices-of-a-square-How-many-neutral-points-will-be-found-inside-the-square).

Comment: In terms of potential there is a potential well at the centre and four saddle points inside the square,